# Get "[Errno 111] Connection refused" error when mount Celery on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I was trying to use Celery to write a backend asynchronous process for my Django project.
I use Rabbitmq as my task queue while using Cloudamqp with Heroku.
The problem is: the whole project works perfectly on my own laptop(using localhost to test),while it didn't work on the production server.

This is the error message I got: `[Errno 111] Connection refused`

Then I did some research, I might be wrong but it seems that the problem is I already reached the limitation of number of worker can be used since i am using a free account for Heroku right now.
I read about this:"But remember to tweak the BROKER_POOL_LIMIT if you’re using the free plan. Set it to 1 and you should be good. If you have connection problems, try reduce the concurrency of both your web workers and in the celery worker." but I am not sure how to do that.

Here is my setting.py:

```
    BROKER_URL="amqp://paswzaog:0TwC3i7cBdTAKA9JE57EMm1xUzovFbry@turtle.rmq.cloudamqp.com/paswzaog"
    BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000  # 5 hours.`
```

Here is the error message:

```
'[Errno 111] Connection refused
'/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.6-py2.7.egg',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/app','
```

Did anybody has a similar problem before? or can someone recommend a thorough tutorial about how to do setting up stuff of Celery onto Heroku? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your credentials might not be valid. Either that or you have more than 1 concurrent connection.

A good way to test this would be to scale your web servers to 0 (heroku scale web=0), then create a single worker (heroku scale worker=1) -- then tail your Heroku logs (heroku logs --tail) to see if your single worker can connect.

Comment: Yeah it turns out that is my credential problem.Thanks for giving me hint!